# HTTP not present on Schemes Swagger dropdown

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I'm using springfox-swagger-ui and for whatever reason, only https scheme is available on the dropdown, even if I reach swagger ui through http. I can't use https for the moment, so need that scheme enabled but couldn't find anything on the documentation. Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these following lines to your `yaml` page:

```
schemes:
  - "https"
  - "http"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("base.package"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()`enter code here`
            .protocols(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("http", "https")));
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDlsa.png)